# Orchard CMS causing System.StackOverflow Exception in w3wp.exe

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, orchardcms, w3wp, mscorlib

I recently installed Orchard V1.8.1 via the Web Platform Installer. It was set up to run on .NET framework 4.0 Integrated mode and I could successfully run the installation script and even managed to log in and install the Metro theme.

However, since this morning, whenever I try to browse to the newly created site, it takes extremely long to load, or rather it doesn't load, my browser just keeps waiting for a response.

I RDP'd into the server and saw that each and every time I try to browse to the site, an error dialog pops up saying that **"An unhandled Microsoft.NET Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe"** And gives me the option of debugging using Visual Studio. When I do that I get an additional message stating that **"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occured in mscorlib.dll".**

This happens only for the Orchard CMS site. There are 5 other custom built sites running on .net version 4.0 integrated mode, though each with their own app pool, naturally.

Again, I don't get these errors in the browser, they're shown in my remote desktop session on the server.

Server details: X64 Windows server 2012, IIS 8.

Comment: Are you able to get a worker process dump you can analyse with WinDBG and SOS? (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/31/net-case-study-stackoverflow-exception-when-using-a-complex-rowfilter.aspx)? these are a great set of tutorials to get you started down the road of debugging gnarly stuff like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact issue, it turned out that I was trying to call the partial it was actually in, therefore getting into a loop.

So within my 'Parts/TabledData/Pagination' .cshtml file I had this:

```
@Html.Partial("Parts/TabledData/Pagination")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is in a fresh install. But you have probably put me on the right track with pointing out an infinite loop can cause this.